# Query failed with error code 6

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

On MongoDB cluster find query from Java application failed with exception:

> com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 6 and error message 'Operation aborted.' on server.

It's happening for both sharded and non-sharded collection. It seems OK when I run single query, but for concurrent query I think it's throwing exception. Also there are no information about error code 6 on MongoDB documentation.

Documents look like:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("58d0652d040213649c38d44a"),
  "number" : "13173403131",
  "user_id" : ObjectId("589dff3374988324008b4567"),
  "add_date" : ISODate("2017-03-30T14:31:27.000Z")
}
```

Find Query:

```
db.blacklist.find({"user_id": ObjectID("589dff3374988324008b4567")})
```

Indexed Filed: "user_id"

Result Set: 1 million data

Comment: It helps to show us what you are actually doing. Where's the query? How big is the data? How big is the expected result set? What indexes are in use if any?

Comment: What is the query exactly? Again Please use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44324507/edit) on the question. See how I made changes. That is what you should be doing.

Comment: I still do not see the query that is being run.